# Powershell Registry / Group Policy change errors

Tags: powershell, registry, group-policy

Im currently working on creating a script in powershell that will edit some settings in the group policy and corresponding registry. Changing the registry has posed no issue, however, the group policy changes will not work.

I am testing my scripts in a closed off VM. The system has to use only native PS commands, so I cant use any add ons or modules. This means I cannot use the PolicyFileEditor module.

No matter what I try, I cant get the group policy to reflect any changes, and the group policy always overrides any registry edits I make.

Can anyone help me figure out what im doing wrong please?

My code is below:

```
# Check if the script is running as an administrator
if (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))

{
    # Restart the script as an administrator
    Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ("-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)")
    Exit
}

# Common path and value names
$commonPath = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\preferences"
$osclientsValueName = "security.osclientcerts.autoload"
$personalCertValueName = "security.default_personal_cert"

try {
    # Set values to "0" (disabled) in the registry
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $commonPath -Name $osclientsValueName -Value "0" -Type String
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $commonPath -Name $personalCertValueName -Value "0" -Type String

    Write-Host "Registry values set successfully."

    # Force a Group Policy update
    gpupdate /force

    Write-Host "Group Policy update completed successfully."
} catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $_"
    # Pause the script to see the error message
    Read-Host "Press Enter to exit..."
}
```

Ive tried changing the path, the item names, the values for the items, and nothing seems to make a difference. I feel like I may be missing something obvious

Comment: the registry and group policy arent on equal mappings for one another. When you GPUpdate, you're just reapplying the existing settings. If you're looking to alter the group policy settings, youd have to look within `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy` folder for the *.pol* files respective to the settings youre trying to change.

Comment: You can use the built-in group policy management module by first enabling it in Roles and Features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=windowsserver2022-ps